# PopUp Calendar Datepicker Error / December Month 12 as 00 and adding a digit to year

Tags: javascript, calendar, datepicker

We have a calendar function on our site which enables people to book reservations. The calendar is visible to the user, but the date gets passed to the booking widget as CIM (check in month), CID (check in day), and CIY (check in year) with comparable dates for Check out.

All has gone well with the scripting until we have received December. It appears that month 12 is getting passed to the booking widget as month "00". I was able to see the fields passed to the form just once. 12/26/2013 and 12/27/2013 were being passed as 00/26/2014 and 00/27/2014 respectively.

I've temporarily gone to a more basic booking widget on the major pages of the site until this can be fixed, so clients can still book rooms. Unfortunately, I am a js newbee and the company I partnered with on this project has only a skeleton crew this week. I am at a loss of what might be wrong with this. [Month 12 is being passed as 00, and in December 2013 is being passed as 2014.]

Could you look at [This web page upon which I've kept the broken script](http://www.stageneck.com/site-map.html). You cannot use dates which have passed and the Inn will be closed from Jan 1-16, so those dates won't work. If you try any other date in 2014 it should work, except again when you get to December, it's broken.

The only thing I could find online as a help was [this post](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/windows-phone/datepicker-and-dateselector/639530.aspx) which has no resolution.

Could something be added to the existing code in js/tcal.js or in my booking widget section that says (to the effect of) when converting get_month if CIM="00" or if COM="00" each of these should be renamed to "12"? Not at all sure why the script may have added a year to 2013 in my first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript's Date object is a little inconsistent:

month ranges from 0 - 11
day ranges from 1 - 31

For December, you're passing 12 to setMonth(), which is outside of the range for month by 1.  That extra 1 is what is incrementing the next value in line, ie. year.

You can change get_nights() to decrement month, and then in pop_fields() increment month so the displayed months range from 1 - 12

```
    function get_nights(date_array){
    var check_in_date = new Date();
    var check_out_date = new Date();
    var check_in_month = parseInt(date_array[0]) - 1;
    var check_out_month = parseInt(date_array[3]) - 1;
    check_in_date.setFullYear(date_array[2]);
    check_in_date.setMonth(check_in_month);
    check_in_date.setDate(date_array[1]);
    check_out_date.setFullYear(date_array[5]);
    check_out_date.setMonth(check_out_month);
    check_out_date.setDate(date_array[4]);
    pop_fields(check_in_date,check_out_date);
}

function pop_fields(check_in,check_out){
var in_month = String(check_in.getMonth() + 1);
    var in_date = String(check_in.getDate());
    var out_month = String(check_out.getMonth() + 1);
    var out_date = String(check_out.getDate());
    document.getElementById('CIM').value = (in_month.length == 1) ? ('0' + in_month) : in_month;
    document.getElementById('CID').value = (in_date.length == 1) ? ('0' + in_date) : in_date;
    document.getElementById('CIY').value = check_in.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById('COM').value = (out_month.length == 1) ? ('0' + out_month) : out_month;
    document.getElementById('COD').value = (out_date.length == 1) ? ('0' + out_date) : out_date;
    document.getElementById('COY').value = check_out.getFullYear();
}
```

Mozilla Developer Network has a good explanation and a couple of examples of this not intuitive behavior on the [Date object page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Dear NickG,

Thank you for replying so quickly. You are my SANTA dearest. Thank you so much. I am sending you love.

Kristi